# Combine data from two columns into one in excel from different sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

So I have two sheets that are set to pull job orders from an external source.  Sheet one will pull Job Order Type A and sheet two pulls Job Order Type B. These sheets will change when refreshed to reflect current active job orders. Both sheets have different amount of columns and headings and I want to create a third sheet to filter and show both Type A and B.   Column A in both sheets has a job order number, how can I extract this column A in both sheets to create a "Master" list of both type A and B.

[image]

I am dealing with a varying number of job orders on each type.  One week could have 300 of type A and then two weeks later it could be 3000.  So dealing with a  large amount of data

Comment: I would guess power pivot (because it's dynamic ranges for both rows and columns).. does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple pivot table with your original table as the source. Add both `TypeA` and `TypeB` fields to Rows section. You will get a single column containing values from both original columns combined.

Comment: I have two original tables, one for TypeA and one for TypeB though.  Can you make a pivot table with two sources?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use "Consolidate multiple ranges" command in pivot table wizard, as described here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in sheet3 copy-paste to cell A2, courtesy of @Jos Wolley

=FILTERXML("**"&TEXTJOIN("****",1,T(IFNA(IF({0,1},Table1[Subject],Table2[Subject]),"")))&"**","//b")

make sure to convert your sheet1 and sheet2 into Tables